# Eclipse (CDT) can't resolve variables?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glut, eclipse-cdt

I'm currently trying to program some OpenGL stuff, but Eclipse is acting strangely.

For some reason, this works:

`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`

and this too:

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

but eclipse says it can't resolve the individual enums here:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? The program compiles and runs just fine despite the error indicated by eclipse. Is there some configuration I can change?

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Is that the intellisense complaining ?

Comment: Auto-completion and stuff is notoriously unreliable. Just because your IDE puts wiggly red underlines on a specific part of your code doesn't mean it's wrong. Only your compiler has the final say in it.

Comment: Your IDE is too stupid to handle bitwise OR'ing `#define`'d constants?   These are not variables in the strictest sense, by the way - they are pre-processor tokens defined in `gl.h`, perhaps your IDE is choking on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a bug in CDT. It can be solved by right clicking the project and clicking rebuild in the index submenu.